# What's needed to develop a database in the cloud?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, non-relational-database

What is needed (in general terms) to create a service like MongoHQ or SimpleDB?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cloud Computing – A Primer** 
http://www.ipjforum.org/?p=199

See Also:

**Is the Relational Database Doomed?** 
http://www.readwriteweb.com/enterprise/2009/02/is-the-relational-database-doomed.php

Comment: Thanks but I'd like to know specifics for a database. Is there any papers for that? thank you